# Connecting AWS MQTT via websocket

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, mqtt, sensors, node-red

I am trying to connect a sensor to an AWS MQTT Broker to a database that will send it to a webserver so that it can be easily accessible. Right now the only way people in our lab can have access to our sensor data is through contacting me directly and having me connect to the Node Red dashboard. Would there be any way for everyone to have access to the data via WebSocket, or at least a couple of people?

I've searched for hours on end and have had no success regarding the ease of accessibility.

From what I've researched there is this a java based client called MQTT.Cool that can connect multiple brokers and have data published via WebSocket using JavaScript. However there is literally no data available except the ones provided by the company. So combining it it with my project has not been an easy task.

Also, I've thought about allowing my node red dashboard to be accessed out of my local
ip-address, but due to security reasons it has been recommended not to be done.

Comment: you can try google iot core mqtt bridge and store it in firebase cloudfirestore. firebase has its own set of library which uses websockets. [link here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge)

Comment: Is it even possible? MQTT and Websockets are two different network protocols.

Comment: Would using google iot core mqtt bridge allow others to access the data easier or have it up on the web so that anyone with permission can view it?

Answer (score 0):

AWS IoT provides an SDK that you can use in your browser:
https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#browser

You can write a web application and view the contents returned by the database after logging in
If you need to browse in real-time, you can use mqtt.js to subscribe to some topics：
https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/connect-to-mqtt-broker-with-websocket

Or use MQTTX, a client tool, to connect directly to the MQTT broker and subscribe to topic